# Enabling ios restrictions from an application

Tags: ios

I have being searching information, tutorials about how to enable a restriction in ios programatically from an installed app. Let say I want to Disable Safari From my "parental control" application remotely, Does IOS allow me to do that and if so how?

Any Ideas?

Comment: No the official iOS SDK does not allow this.

Comment: Any suggestions? Optional workaround to control iOS restrictions from an APP, OR maybe doing something similar?

Comment: No there is none, since you cannot access the system in that way. On iOS apps are sandboxed and trying to acces other parts of the system, outside of the sandbox just is not allowed.